# PhpStorm configure vendor extensions individually

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have the following Magento 2 standard project structure, but this can apply to any php composer based project:

```
.
..
.git
.gitignore
composer.json
composer.lock
vendor/Acme/module1
vendor/Acme/module1/composer.json
vendor/Acme/module1/.git

# .gitignore contains a directive to ignore the vendor directory because the project structure contains nested repositories
```

Is there a way to configure PhpStorm to highlight my changes individually for each vendor extension? At this point all my vendor changes are not displayed (because of the directive in the .gitignore file). The only changes that are highlighted are the ones in the main project repo.

Comment: `vendor` should rather be kind of read-only. You should not edit much there as part of regular development

Comment: I am not talking about editing core libraries. Magento 2 development can be extension based. What this means is that you can host your custom developed code as a vendor extension or as part of the src directory. If you chose to go on the extension based workflow you will most likely code directly in the vendor/Acme/YourModule directory. I guess this applies to other frameworks like Symfony or Laravel.

Comment: what I am saying is that you should be able to remove `vendor` completely and repopulate it with `composer install` to the same state. Therefore vendor is your runtime "asset" providing all libs your code needs but this should not be part of your project code (and even excluded from your VCS) besides `composer.json` and perhaps `composer.lock` files.

Comment: It's not a good practice to  change anything in /vendor// because it will be erased during running `composer install`

Comment: Maybe it's better solution to install your composer module [via symlink](https://johannespichler.com/developing-composer-packages-locally/) from some child folder?

Answer (score 2):

You may install your vendor module via symlink using this manual https://johannespichler.com/developing-composer-packages-locally/

Then you can add this external folder to your project to simplify development via `File | Settings | Directories | Add Content Root` action.

[image]

Then you need to add your module VCS to your project via `File | Settings | Version Control`
[image]

Now you can easily manage your changes separately.
[image]

For even better control I recommend you use [changelists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-changelists.html)